# Using the _mint() function from an ERC20 contract marked 'internal virtual'

Tags: erc-20, tokens, mint, virtual

I have an existing ERC20 token / contract that I would like to be able to provide rewards that could be minted to the supply. The existing contract already has a `_mint()` function, but it's labeled as 'internal virtual.' It isn't private, and its part of the ERC20 declared construct, so I assume it's accessible.

How do I either: Extend the contract to access this `_mint()` function for rewards, or create a new contract that can perform the functions of this one with its approval?

Current contract code looks like this:

```
contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata {
...
...
     function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);

        _totalSupply += amount;
        _balances[account] += amount;
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);

        _afterTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your current contract is not deployed yet, you can create a new contract that inherits from your current contract and exposes a function externally (external or public) that calls `super._mint(...)`.

Have a look at the following snippet:

```
contract SomeContract is ERC20 {
...

    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) external override {
        ...
        super._mint(account, amount);
        ...
    }

...
}
```

If your current contract is already deployed, you are not able to invoke the `_mint(...)` function.